# Getting first the terms starting with the string I am searching for

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, ajax

I am using Drupal 7. I add one vocabulary in taxonomy and I am using it as auto-complete in user's registration.

Now I have a problem with how it search.

[image]

When I enter *y*, it shows taxonomy terms containing *y*, but I wanted to first see the terms that start with *y*.

There is [module](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_autocomplete_settings) to set this settings, but this module doesn't support Drupal 7.

How can get first the terms starting with the string I am searching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Taxonomy Autocomplete Settings](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_autocomplete_settings) module has now a Drupal 7 version, and an official release (7.x-1.0).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I know a pretty easy way around this. (Actually 2).

First way is to update that module you linked to up to D7.

Second way is to create a small module, and use the D6 code needed for your autocomplete.

1. Create a D7 module skeleton, or a simple [hello world module](http://reinholdweber.com/2010/06/28/create-your-first-simple-drupal-7-module/) that can be found lying around.
2. Get your .info and .module file working.
3. Find the code in the module you linked that rearranges the autocomplete,
4. Rip it out. Ctr-c the %&% out of that old outdated D6 code.
5. Implement the same code in your module (hint: ctrl-v)
6. Don't tell anyone. Unless you ultimately *share* that code, then read the licences of the code you are using  and  give credits where due according to those terms.
7. Most important: Check the code you just ripped.  Learn something out of it, if possible. See how it works, why it does it. If it can be improved, even.

Good-luck, just message me if you need further help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Well since the answer  stefgosselin gave is not really very helpful, cut and paste does simply not work. I built a module for drupal 7 and attached it to an issue, so if you want to test it or have questions or want to contribute check it out under:

http://drupal.org/node/1413974